# JAVA2d Setting element on right place

Tags: java, awt, java-2d

I'm writing a simple game in JAVA2D. I created a class "Ground". When I create an object of this class like that...

```
Ground g1 = new Ground("WATER", 50, 100, 5, 5) //params: type of surface, margin-left,     margin-top, width, height
```

...I create a square 5x5 pixels (in JAVA2D fillRect function). Now I want to set this square in any place on my frame. It's a simple example in HTML: When we want to move a simple box in HTML we use styles

```
<div style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 100px"></div>
```

and voila. In JAVA there are only Layouts which don't help me with that. Layouts don't give me a freedom of setting margins.

setBounds does not work

Comment: Although, it is not very advisable option, but you can go without layout manager - a so called absolute positioning. See [Doing Without a Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

Answer (score 0):

setBounds() should work as long as you set the layout to null I have some code here that demonstrates this

```
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Test extends JFrame
    {
       private JPanel panel;
       private JButton button;

       public Test()
       {
           panel = new JPanel();
           button = new JButton("I am a Button");
           panel.setLayout(null);
           button.setBounds(80,100,50,50);
           panel.add(button);

           this.setTitle("setBounds() Test");
           this.setSize(480,340);
           this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           this.setVisible(true);
           this.getContentPane().add(panel);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
           new Test();
       }
 }
```